# Add Array of label to collection view cell

Tags: iphone, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i want to add this label array to collectionview cell

```
labelArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Theme 001-002", @"Theme 002-006", @"Theme 006-009", @"Theme 009-012", nil];


NSString *filePath = [labelArray indexPath.row];
```

Is this the right way to add label array to collectionview cell.

```
cell.label.text = @"Theme 001-002";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
labelArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Theme 001-002", @"Theme 002-006", @"Theme 006-009", @"Theme 009-012", nil];


cell.label.text = [labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```